# Large(r) files with camel-ws - Memory

Tags: web-services, file, out-of-memory, cxf, apache-camel

We use camel with a webservice-endpoint starting a route. This works well so far. Now I tested some 'larger' file of just 15MB and the route runs into a `OutOfMemoryError`. Heapsize is 1280MB (`-Xms128m -Xmx1280m`).

Is there a limit for the memory, a route may use? I winder, that a 15MB file could not be received with the tomcat using 1280 MB of memory.

Did I miss some configuration?

---

Sry for answering late, I had same time off.

The route looks like this, I think this doesn't really help ;-):

```
this.from(this.createWsEndpoint(...))
.routeId("some id")
.process(new AuthentificationProcessor(...))
.process(this.getAddMetadataProcessor())
.process(this.getArchiveToDbProcessor())
.to(this.getProducerJpaEndpoint())
```

Anyway, ftp seems to be the future for this case.

Comment: What does your camel router looks like?

Comment: Well 15MB of XML is pretty huge it is not large it is huge. Would also like to see your route.